# ¿Cuándo se usa "hacer estragos"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, modismos, expresiones

Leo lo siguiente en [un artículo de Josep Ramoneda](http://ccaa.elpais.com/ccaa/2015/07/31/catalunya/1438356891_248450.html):

> Durante las dos décadas anteriores a la crisis de 2008, **la creencia
>   en que no había límites**, en que todo era posible, **hizo estragos**
>   y coronó como nuevo dios a los inefables mercados de los que emana no
>   sólo la obligación política si no también la normatividad moral.

Lo que me lleva a mirar en la RAE:

> [**estrago**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=GwTCO0S)
>   De *estragar*.
>   1. m. Daño hecho en guerra, como una matanza de gente, o la destrucción de la campaña, del país o del ejército.
>   2. m. Ruina, daño, asolamiento.
>   *causar, o hacer, estragos*
>   1. locs. verbs. Provocar una fuerte atracción o una gran admiración entre un grupo de personas.

Y luego:

> [**estragar**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=GwRZHel)
>   (Del lat. vulg. *stragāre, asolar, devastar).
>   1. tr. viciar (‖ corromper física o moralmente). U. t. c. prnl.
>   2. tr. Causar estrago.

Y me surge la duda: ¿en qué casos se usa "hacer/causar estragos"? Siempre pensé que se refería a algo malo, del tipo "el huracán hizo estragos en las costas", pero al parecer también tiene cierto punto de admiración.

Comment: Admiración negativa claro.

Comment: Pasaba por aquí, una buena pregunta que generó dos buenas respuestas, con 0 votos por 11 meses (deduzco que yo tampoco voté). [¿Se vota poco en este Stack?](http://meta.spanish.stackexchange.com/q/2446/6915)

Comment: @Rodrigo de hecho debo reconocer que la refloté un poquito por eso, me dio penita que pasara tan desapercibida :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probablemente el sentido admirativo se apoye en que aquello que hace estragos suele ser algo de gran alcance, imparable, contra lo que es inútil resistirse: *Su película hizo estragos entre los adolescentes*.

Con «arrasar» ocurre más o menos lo mismo: *Los Beatles arrasaron en los años sesenta*. En este caso creo que es más fácil hacer la distinción porque pierde la transitividad.

Answer (score 3):

`Causar estragos` se suele usar con dos significados muy opuestos, el sentido más literal implica grandes daños, destrozos, consecuencias de alguna catástrofe (natural o humana), etc. Por ejemplo, `la tormenta de piedra ha causado estragos en la zona rural rompiendo autos, vidrios y destrozando las plantaciones`.

Por otro lado, se puede usar para resaltar que algo tuvo un éxito rotundo, como podría ser `el delantero causó estragos en la defensa contraria y marcó los tres goles en la victoria de su equipo`.

En este caso en particular `la creencia en que no había límites, en que todo era posible, hizo estragos` da a pensar que utiliza la connotación negativa de la frase, refiriendo tal vez a que estos hechos rompieron de forma total el paradigma que estaba establecido.